# how to create serverless functions (get requests) with nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, serverless, next.js13

I am used to create simple api endpoints via nextjs serverless functions. I had an api folder inside my pages folder which contains all my endpoints. I just created a new repository with nextjs 13 which uses the app router instead of the pages one. I don't get how to create new routes.

I found this in the docs:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return NextResponse.json({ hello: "Next.js" });
}
```

So I tried to add it within `app/api/route.ts`, but querying localhost:3000/api/route returns me a 404 error. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new app router the `route.ts` file has special meaning and is not part of the endpoint url. So in your case for `app/api/route.ts` the resulting url is `localhost:3000/api` for `localhost:3000/api/route` you would need to structure it as `app/api/route/route.ts` or for `localhost:3000/api/foo/bar` it would be `app/api/foo/bar/route.ts` etc. The `route.ts` file indicates that the handler defined in that file applies to the path corresponding to the parent folder. Also the file needs to be called `route.js|ts` calling it `something_else.ts` will not work.